Playing steel drum on a keyboard
I'm playing a calypso number, and decided to use the steel drum (pan) sound from the GM (general MIDI) set of sounds available. The sound is pretty authentic, but I'm struggling to emulate the 'drum roll' effect that pan players use most often.
Does anyone have any tips to make the playing sound more authentic?

What's the technique you're currently using?

@ToddWilcox - rolling full chords with both hands, with one hand, rolling dyads, but nothing sounds the same as a pan, which I used to play many years ago, as in rolling one section of the pan as in a drum roll.

I've only had two steel pan lessons and maybe four hours of total playing time, so I'm not certain. My gut says this may be something that is going to be near impossible without a percussion controller of some sort. Sometimes fingers on keys just can't replicate the sounds of percussion techniques.

Is your steel drum sound touch sensitive with a full range of dynamic sampling?

Since you already had experience with the physical instruments, the basic approach is to try to apply the same concepts you're aware of: what you would or could do with the real instrument.
In steel pans, you normally play only one note per hand, so playing dyads on each hand will obviously result "unnatural".
If you really need chords based on more than two notes, then you have to apply the conceptual technique you'd use on the instrument, which is to alternate hands and switch as many notes each hand could play, similarly to a "tremolo" effect.
For instance, for a G7 chord, supposing that the left hand would play G and B, while the right plays D and F, then you should try to play the following possible alternated pattern:
G (left middle finger)
D (right thumb)
B (left thumb)
F (right middle finger)

Steel pan techniques are not that limited, though: "bounced" strokes are quite common, and you can even imitate them as well; consider this "arpeggio style":
G (left middle finger)
B (left thumb)
D (right thumb)
F (right middle finger)

You could even invert the order of one hand, or both. But, in any case, try to avoid more than one note played exactly at the same time or recognizable patterns of double strokes, because they would have a very different effect.
In any case, the idea is that you have to try to imitate the result of the most effective technique that would be used on the original instrument in order to play what you want.
Also consider that tremolo often requires a certain level of detachment from the tempo, because it usually is an "unmeasured" tremolo.
The rhythmic subdivisions between hands or fingers is almost never an arithmetic subdivision based on the beats. While it often is "as fast as possible" and ends the pattern when the effect should (no matter the last hand/note before the final one), in reality, the "note frequency" is a specific choice that depends on the musical context and personal choices: even for the same time (not tempo based) duration, one could choose to make the "subdivision quality" (the frequency) faster or slower.
Sometimes you could even choose to change the frequency along the overall length of the effect, exactly as a classical instrument player would do for a similar ornament such as a trill, which is rarely based on a constant time frequency of the involved notes.

Don't try to do the roll too fast.
I don't think this is about keyboard technique, more about the limitations of the sample. You can't build a drum roll sound by rapidly repeating a single hit - it just sounds like a machine gun.  I suspect the same principle holds for your steel drum.  Work within the limitations of the sound you have available.

Having explored many different options, the most successful notes for each chord to sound are 3rds and/or 6ths.
As far as playing those simple intervals is concerned, several ideas cropped up. One was to use the middle fingers of each hand in a similar way to drumsticks. Not so successful, as the rhythm wasn't easy to keep - the roll was uneven.
So, one handed worked better. Either using two fingers to 'roll', which wasn't too bad, but the best so far is playing 6ths, rocking the hand from side to side, using mainly thumb and pinky.There is more control that way, so that's where I am.
